# Java for test automation; beginner's issue with code execution

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, appium

I'm learning test automation and I've got stuck while trying to write a java code to open an Android emulator and then an app on it.

**That's my code:**

```
    package com.company;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // write your code here

        File f=new File("src");
        File fs=new File(f, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Demo");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());

        AndroidDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4732/wd/hub"), cap);

    }
}
```

**And that's a log:**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.<clinit>(Json.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.constructMessage(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.<init>(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:29)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:39)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:25)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: This is a mismatch in the dependency versions for selenium / gson

Comment: You should add Appium to your post tags.

Comment: @user180100 your comment should be an answer and marked as accepted. It help me overcome an identical issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have basic Java programming knowledge and new to Appium, the best you can do is to check how appium contributors write their tests for Android on [java-client repository](https://github.com/appium/java-client/tree/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android).

Just a few tips:

- `BaseAndroidTest.java` tells you how to *start server programmatically* and *create instance of Android driver*
- `AndroidElementTest.java` tells you how to *find elements*

Spend the time analysing the code I mentioned and play with it on your local machine. Hope that helps you to make a next step in learning automation.

Answer (score 0):

My ApiDemo.apk worked with these combinations. I think the trick lies in selecting emulator/device and relating APK file.

ApiDemo.apk

My Emulator/device is Android 6  (having Android 23) so used the apk file from the system images from my sdk file.

(This  file I got it from  sdk file `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android- 23\google_apis\x86\data\app\ApiDemos\ApiDemos.apk`)

REST ALL I USED CURRENT VERSION JARS

```
Selenium-java-3.8.1
appium java client-6.0.0.0-BETA1.jar
common-lang3-3.7 jars
gson 2.8.2.jar  (Need to download gson jar seprately)
```

Appium version 1.6.5  or current version  1.7.1 ( on the above combination jar file and apk file it worked well on both the appium versions ,I am able to open the app and interact with the elements).

Giving the entire configuration so that you can start with your further lessons.